# Attaching content scripts to chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension already attaches content scripts to all pages and iframes, however I don't see it get attached to windows opened with `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`. Is there a way to make that happen? Furthermore, I am particularly interested in my content scripts getting attached to auth windows launched by other extensions.

Comment: It seems that either you need a permission in your manifest, or it cannot be used in the current content script.

Keep in mind to add "identity" permission in the manifest. It's specified in the documentation header. Like "permissions": [
  "identity"
] See the reference: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.